# Angular 6 router returns index.html for api call in asp.net mvc

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Hello I'm creating an angular app with ASP.NET MVC and using web api for data transfer, before integrating angular with my asp.net project the api calls were working fine but after I had configured angular with asp.net mvc project, API calls are not working now. It returns the HTTP 200 status means call are OK but response is like 
[image]

And its headers..

[image]

Angular component..

```
apiCall() {
    this.http.get('api/Angular').subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
}
```

HTTPSERVICE

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()

export class HttpService {

local: string = "http://localhost:4545/"

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


get(url: string): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.local + url);
}

post(url: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(url, data);
}

put(url: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(url, data);
}
```

}

This is my Layout where angular is configured to load in mvc project

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>My ASP.NET Application</title>
<base href="/" />
</head>
<body>

<div>
    @RenderBody()
</div> 
<script src="~/ClientApp/dist/BabyShared/polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/ClientApp/dist/BabyShared/runtime.js"></script>
<script src="~/ClientApp/dist/BabyShared/styles.js"></script>
<script src="~/ClientApp/dist/BabyShared/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="~/ClientApp/dist/BabyShared/main.js"></script>
```

Api Controller..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace BabyWeb.Api
{
    public class AngularController : ApiController
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "Angular";
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

Even if i try to access api call via browser it fails. I think I have messed up angular routing and asp.net routing in this configuration. Please do help me out.

Comment: Everything looks OK to me, can we see the controller endpoint for /api/Angular?

Comment: Hi bgraham I had added info of api controller.

Comment: It happens even when i try to call http://localhost:4545/api/angular

Comment: Sorry, nothing jumps out at me. Everything looks OK. Are you getting a 404 response? kind of silly but does localhost:4545/api/angular/Get return anything?

Comment: No i get 200 HttpStatus. Ya it returns index.html page!! I dont know why

Comment: Sorry, haven't been helpful yet. Can you share your global.asax? Sounds like maybe the routing configuration there is grabbing everything, but it should be ignoring api routes potentially.

Comment: I have added the info. No problem buddy atleast you are trying to help me out with this. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been days to search for the solution, but pretty clearly I just messed up with my urlrewrite config in web.config. Actually what happened was I had  problem of 404 error while reload on angular router so I did the url rewrite but haven't thought that I ll also have to ignore the routes starting with "api/" so that it wont return me index.html.

Here's the solution.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" /> /// I missed this line
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Link: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: Are you using `dotnet run` to start your app, or just running via IIS?

Comment: Running via IIS

Comment: Is ther a way I could add this in .net Core APP the ^(api) part

Answer (score 0):

Still not positive what the problem is. Here's something you can try because I see attribute routing is enabled:

```
namespace BabyWeb.Api
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Angular")]
    public class AngularController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("")]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "Angular";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not positive this would work, but the documentation seems to indicate attribute routes should trump default routing.

Can you try to figure out what returns the index.html? Because its a single page app, there should be configuration somewhere that says basically always return the index.html and then the Angular routing will take over from there. Potentially in the RouteConfig.cs file. Anyways, we need to disable it from doing that on /api routes.